# Force image width and height PHP

Tags: php

I have a CMS website that displays user's images.  The site currently uses an array to display the max. image width, however this is breaking my design a little and I'd like to force the images to a set width and height.

In one of the files the image is referenced using the following code:

```
$rs_model_shout[$c]['vImageUrl'] = getImageURL($rs_model_shout[$c]['vImage'], getModelImagePath($rs_model_shout[$c]['iModelId'])."/", getModelImageURL($rs_model_shout[$c]['iModelId'])."/", $imgNamePrefix='2_', $imgDefaultURL=$site_url.'images/default.jpg');
```

How can I edit this to specify width and height?  I tried just adding width="80" height="100", but this made no changes.

Thanks!!

I tried to view the output, but still receive a blank page.  Maybe I am entering the var_dump incorrectly?

```
<?php
ob_start();
var_dump($rs_model_shout[$c]['vImage']);
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", "On");
$result = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Comment: Could you post the result of that function? e.g. `var_dump` of `$rs_model_shout[$c]['vImageUrl']`

Comment: I tried this but I received a blank page:

<?php
ob_start();
var_dump($rs_model_shout[$c]['vImageUrl']);
$result = ob_get_clean();
?>

Comment: Usually means there's an error somewhere. Chuck a `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", "On");` in there. Edit your answer and put the result of that underneath :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work, however the answer was not in the php line of code I originally thought..

On a different file there was a reference to the img src which I was able to edit with the following:

```
<img src="'.$rs_model_shout[$v]['vImage_url'].'" alt="'.$rs_model_shout[$v]['vShoutTitle'].'" style="width:150px;" height="200px;" />
```